# move loop selection to next or previous loop?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools, edges

I am trying to move the selected loop to next loop (the first selected loop needs to be deselected as well, what i need help with is to move the selection not expand it. Is it any command in blender that does this? it does not matter how i get the result so switching selection modes etc will work since i will just copy the order of commands that it takes to get this result in Blender and write a script for it.

See pic,

[image]

Comment: Quite dirty solution is to use vertex groups, so each loopcut assigned per group. You then select / deselect vertex groups in desired order. There would be a lot of those groups though.

Comment: Mr Zak, yeah i read about this in another tread, it just seems so wierd that there is no easier way for this. Anyway more reading on my part i guess, thanks!